# function levenshtein does not exist error periodically occurs in postgres

Tags: postgresql

Periodically (I'd guess every 3 months) I start getting the following error:

```
function levenshtein(unknown, character varying) does not exist
```

Each time I re-add the function like this:

```
CREATE EXTENSION fuzzystrmatch SCHEMA public;
```

and everything works again. But... seemingly without cause, the error will start happening months later. This is happening in a production environment so beyond the occasional restart, there's no changes or triggers I can see for this. It also happens on my dev machine.

The question is really, what kind of situations could cause this function to disappear beyond manually uninstalling it (which I'm not doing)?

Comment: Start logging all connections and all DDL.

Comment: In particular, set `log_statement = 'ddl'` and have `log_line_prefix` include `%u` and `%h`.

Comment: Will do - any tips for what I should look out for in the logs?